how to pass post data into iframe in react
I want yo post a data, post data will be show in iframe.
my Html code working good. how to do this in react.
<iFrame src="http://127.0.0.1/iframe_post/test.php" name="hidden_iframe" height="300" width="500"></iFrame>
<form id="loginForm" target="hidden_iframe" action="http://127.0.0.1/iframe_post/test.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="j_username" value="login" />
    <input type="text" name="j_password" value="password" />
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
$name = $_POST["j_username"];
$pass = $_POST["j_password"];

echo $name;
echo $pass;
?>

Note: in react, any form not available. iframe available with out srcDoc(like in html) just React.useEffect will post a data & data will be show in iframe. how to load iframe with POST response.

What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?  Why would the functionality need to be any different in React?  Or, perhaps putting it another way... What is the actual underlying functionality you are trying to build in React and what purpose does it serve?  (As there may be a better way to accomplish it overall.)
